# Is the mahamrityunjaya mantra the same mantra given by Shiva to Shukracharya to revive the dead?

Tags: shiva, mantras

Shukracharya apparently asked that the Asuras to be compensated for being cheated out of Amrita and after his austerities Shiva gave him the mrita sanjivani mantra.  Is it the same as the Mahamrityunjaya mantra?

Comment: Its a variant of this mantra called mrita sanjeevani vidya

Comment: haha @LakshmiNarayanan What happened to you? :-)

Comment: @Rohit. Fighting vidandaavaatham on this site. It is growing to perverse levels.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No** it is not the same MahAmrityunjaya Mantra. It is a special Mantra which is formed by combining the GAyatri Mantra and the Mrityunjaya Mantra in a certain manner. It has a special name viz- "ShukropAsita Mrityunjaya Mantra" Or "the Mrityunjaya Mantra which was worshipped/practiced/mastered by Shukra"

Quoting from the Krishnachandra AgamvAgis's TantraSAra's pp 505:

> atha shukropAsita mrityunjaya mantrah ||
>
> gAyatri prathamam pAdam tryambakapAdyeikam tathA |
>  gAyatri
>   dvitiyam pAdam tryambakadvitiyam pAdam |
>  gAyatritritiyam pAdam
>   tryambaka sheshapAdam || 
> mantro tathA - Om tatsavitur varenyam
>   tryambkam yajAmahe sugandhim pushtivardhanam vargodevasya ... ||

The Mantra is thus formed by combining the GAyatri Mantra and the Tryambaka Mantra as follows:

> First part of GAyatri is added first followed by the first part of the
>   Tryambaka Mantra. Thereafter, GAyatri Mantra's second part is added
>   and followed by Tryambaka's second part. Then added is GAytri Mantra's
>   third part and similarly followed by Tryambaka's third part.

It is now easy to see what the Mantra turns out to be finally. Not giving in full but it is like this **" Om tatsavitur varenyam tryambkam yajAmahe sugandhim pushtivardhanam vargodevasya .... ||"**

The way/technique this Mantra is formed (by prefixing/suffixing Mantras to another Mantra) is known in the Tantras as *Samputana*.

Then the text gives the DhyAnam for Tryamabaka MahArudra, who is to be worshipped and the Japa is thereafter to be done.

> Evam dhyAtvAvAhya tryambakAya mahArudrAya namah ityanena pujayet |
>   asya japAt sarvasiddhirbhavati ||

This passage says that Puja Mantra to be used in the Prayoga is ""tryambka mahArudrAya namaha". And, it also says that chanting of this Mantra bestows all sorts of fulfillments.

UPDATE:

However, note that, there is another Mantra called the Mritasanjivani Mantra dedicated to Lord Shiva. It is also derived from the Tryambaka Mantra by adding a prefix (X) both before and after the usual Tryambaka Mantra.

The Prefix X is- a combination of the "Bhur Bhuvah Swah"+"Joom Sah" (not giving the exact Mantra though).

But, it is not mentioned in the text whether Shukra worshipped it or not.

Comment: just HOW do you find these things :-) ?  Thats astounding.  In light of this, one would have to be fanatically anti-Siva to deny that the RigVedic mantra is dedicated to Rudra.

Comment: Rick, I'd like you to be circumspect about giving away mantras in answers. Especially in times where the gayatri is being remixed into club music and played in bars and pubs.

Comment: Yes i mostly don't give too at least not the Mantras from the Agamas. But Mantras won't work without initiation. Plus there are several other hindrances on the way of making it work for us. So, it is not possible that someone takes a Mantra from one of my answers and use it for his benefit @moonstar

Comment: The Rigvedic Mantra is dedicated to Lord Rudra. Everyone knows that. also thank u.. i just know a lil bit by reading some books and scriptures. I buy a lot of books on such subjects actually. @SK

Comment: Misusing and abusing mantras (with or without initiation) is a loka vinasana hetu.

Comment: yeah @moonstar- it would be AWFUL if the secret of Brahmastra gets out - what if it falls into the wrong hands?

Comment: I usually do not give. But it is not possible to answer this particular one without giving the Mantra. So, will take care of it in the future. @moonstar

Comment: sarcasm : D-  humor : F  @SK

Comment: Its used for improving health and vitality . how it can be misused

Comment: @RakeshJoshi She must be generally concerned.