# What's exact "ShukropAsita Mrityunjaya Mantra"?

Tags: shiva, mantras, shukracharya

Can someone tell me the exact "ShukropAsita Mrityunjaya Mantra" which is the combination of mrutyunjay mantra and gayatri mantra?

Comment: Mentioned in the answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26818/is-the-mahamrityunjaya-mantra-the-same-mantra-given-by-shiva-to-shukracharya-to/26832#26832

Comment: Is it only "Om tatsavitur varenyam tryambkam yajAmahe sugandhim pushtivardhanam vargodevasya" this much ? can you please write in devnagri? I would also like to know the "Mritasanjivani" mantra in devnagri.

Comment: I can write in Devanagari and no that's not the full mantra .. but you can easily know what it is if u follow the method I gave in that answer .. you just need to know the Gayatri and Mahamrityunjaya mantras

Answer (score 1):

You can find it on http://muktalib5.org/digital_library_secure_entry.htm
in  brhattantrasāra :

```
     "oṃ tatsaviturvareṇyaṃ tryambakaṃ yajāmahe sugandhiṃ
      puṣṭivarddhaṇaṃ bhargo devasya dhīmahi urvārukamivabandhanāt
      dhiyo yo naḥ pracodayāt (mṛtyormukṣīyamāmṛtāt)"
```